# How to implement a custom Toast in Sencha Touch app?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to custom a `Toast`in Sencha touch but instead of pop-up centered, a Toast appearing from the right side and fade out.. like "push-notification" style.

It is trivial to custom styles and other parameters but I did not find the correct way to implement this layout.

Here you can see a fiddle with a basic custom implementation:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a1v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saved over your fiddle, try this

```
Ext.toast({
    message:'Hello Sencha!',
    centered: false,
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    top: 0,
    right: 10
});
```

Comment: If you want to change the animation, you should take a look at the showAnimation/hideAnimation configs and set them with the animation you want. Not sure if that was working perfectly on Sencha Touch though

Comment: By the way, I am looking showAnimation is not working, but with this conf is working correctly: `Ext.toast({
        message: label,
        centered: false,
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        top: '80%',
        hideOnMaskTap: false,
        right: 10,
        type: 'slide', duration: 850, easing: 'ease-out',
        hideAnimation: {type: 'fadeOut', duration: 650, easing: 'ease-out'},
        timeout: 3000
      });`    but I don´t know why...  any clue?